# Tidy Eval - pass mutated column to a group by - R

Tags: r, tidyeval

I'm running into an issue passing a column being created in mutate to the the group_by function.

here is some example data:

```
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility

w2_test <- data.frame(id=1:607, 
                      wave = "W2",
                      tech =floor(runif(607, 1, 6)))
```

This function does recoding of Likert scales

```
recoding_1_fn <- function(var_name) {
  var_name_ <- case_when(
    var_name %in% c(1, 2, 3, 6) ~ "disagree",
    var_name %in% c(4, 5) ~ "agree",
    TRUE ~ NA
  )
}
```

and this function attempts to summarize n by the recoded scales above

```
summary_w2_fn <- function(df, w2_name, w3_name, suffix = "recoded") {
  
  df %>% 
    rename({{w3_name}} := {{w2_name}}) %>%
    count(wave, {{w3_name}}) %>%
    drop_na() %>% 
    mutate("{{w3_name}}_{suffix}" := recoding_1_fn({{w3_name}})) %>% 
    group_by(wave, "{{w3_name}}_{suffix}") %>%
    summarise(n = sum(n)) %>% 
    rename("{{w3_name}}" := "{{w3_name}}_{suffix}")
}
```

when called This above function works up until the mutate function

```
w2 %>% summary_w2_fn(tech, W3_SUS_4)
```

and I get a dataset that looks like this:

[df up until mutate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXeRI.png)

If I let it run to the group_by, it won't recognize the column "{{w3_name}}_{suffix}" and I get the following

[df up until summarise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewFcE.png)

I've tried a number of enquo, quos, !!, etc. but really at random, since I'm stuck, nothing has worked.

If there a way that I can pass the column being created in mutate to the next function?

You help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Comment: This is a tidy evaluation problem: in your second screenshot, notice that the column name includes double quotes. Read up on NSE in the tidyverse.  Also, I suspect, from the use of `_suffix`, that your data frame is not tidy. If so, your life in the tidyverse is always going to be more difficult than it needs to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested since you didn't provide a reprex:

```
summary_w2_fn <- function(df, w2_name, w3_name, suffix = "recoded") {
  recoded_name <- rlang::englue("{{w3_name}}_{suffix}")
  
  df %>% 
    rename({{w3_name}} := {{w2_name}}) %>%
    count(wave, {{w3_name}}) %>%
    drop_na() %>% 
    mutate("{recoded_name}" := recoding_1_fn({{w3_name}})) %>% 
    group_by(wave, .data[[recoded_name]]) %>%
    summarise(n = sum(n))
}
```

I removed the last expression because it had the structure of a `filter()` but it was a call to `rename()`, something looks wrong.

Comment: Amazing @Lionel. when I add back the rename function as 
    rename({{w3_name}} := .data[[recoded_name]])
I get the warning: Use of .data in tidyselect expressions was deprecated in tidyselect 1.2.0.
ℹ Please use `all_of(var)` (or `any_of(var)`) instead of `.data[[var]]`.  How do we address that?

Comment: You can use `all_of(var)` like the message suggests. I guess another operator for single variables would be better here, but we don't have one.